# How to get terms for taxonomy

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

how to get all terms for my taxonomy customcategorie i tried with this code

i tried to keep code in taxonomy.php

```
<?php

/*
Template Name:Taxoo



*/
get_header();



?>




<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); ?>
<h2> 

<?php
$args = array(
'type' => 'post',
'child_of' => 0,
'parent' => 0,
'orderby' => 'name',
'order' => 'ASC',
'hide_empty' => 0,
'hierarchical' => 1,
'taxonomy' => 'customcategorie'
);

foreach ( get_categories( $args ) as $taxonomy_cat ) {
  echo '<li>' . 
    wp_get_attachment_image( $taxonomy_cat->term_image, 'thumbnail' ) . 
    $taxonomy_cat->name . 
    '</li>';
}



?>













<?php

get_footer();


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<?php
//list terms in a given taxonomy
$taxonomy = 'industry';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: taxonomy terms are getting can we get image for that i added in taxonomy.php in am using this plugin https://github.com/daggerhart/taxonomy-term-image in taxonomy-customcategorie.php i am getting image but i was not able to get in taxonomy.php